# Why my chisel code written to generate axi4 pins on Sifive's E310 SOC didn't work?

Tags: scala, riscv, chisel

This year I got a project aims to design a SOC system based on RISCV core. I intended to used the Sifive E310 Soc then what I need to do is just to do a little bit tunning. The key of which is to add a AXI4 port on the system.

Luckily the rocket core uses "cake pattern" to add peripheries. I have added trait CanHaveMasterAXI4MMIOPort and HasPeripheryVGAModuleImp to E300Nexys4DDRDevKitSystem. And wrote a AxiPins.scala file to match the AXI4 ports to with the Pins of AXI4 defined at the top of the system. just like any other peripheries added by Sifive. I'v passed the compiliation. Sadly, the generated verilog file didn't see any AXi4 Pins at top :(:(:(
[Cann't find any AXI4 Pins added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roLLo.jpg)
The AXI4 pins file is written like this:

```
package sifive.blocks.devices.axi

import Chisel._
import chisel3.util.{Irrevocable}
import freechips.rocketchip.config.{Field, Parameters}
import chisel3.experimental.{withClockAndReset}
import freechips.rocketchip.util._
import freechips.rocketchip.amba.axi4.{AXI4Bundle,AXI4BundleBase,AXI4BundleParameters}
import sifive.blocks.devices.pinctrl.{Pin, PinCtrl}

case object PeripheryaxiKey extends Field[Seq[AXI4BundleParameters]]

    class AXI4_Pins_BASE[T <: Data](private val pingen: () => T, private val c:AXI4BundleParameters) extends Bundle


    class AXI4BundleB_pin[T <: Data](pingen:() => T, c:AXI4BundleParameters) extends AXI4_Pins_BASE(pingen, c) {
     val id   = UInt(width = c.idBits)
     val resp = UInt(width = c.respBits)
    }

class AXI4BundleR_pin[T <: Data](pingen:() => T, c:AXI4BundleParameters) extends AXI4_Pins_BASE(pingen, c) {
  val id   = UInt(width = c.idBits)
  val data = UInt(width = c.dataBits)
  val resp = UInt(width = c.respBits)
  val last = Bool()

}





class AXI4_Pins[T <: Pin]( pingen: () => T, c:AXI4BundleParameters) extends AXI4_Pins_BASE(pingen, c) {

  val aw_id     = Vec(c.idBits, pingen())
  val aw_addr   = Vec(c.addrBits, pingen())
  val aw_len    = Vec(c.lenBits, pingen())  // number of beats - 1
  val aw_size   = Vec(c.sizeBits, pingen()) // bytes in beat = 2^size
  val aw_burst  = Vec(c.burstBits, pingen())
  val aw_lock   = Vec(c.lockBits, pingen())
  val aw_cache  = Vec(c.cacheBits, pingen())
  val aw_prot   = Vec(c.protBits, pingen())
  val aw_qos    = Vec(c.qosBits, pingen())  // 0=no QoS, bigger = higher priority
  val aw_valid =  pingen()
  val aw_ready =  pingen()


  val w_data = Vec(c.dataBits, pingen()) 
  val w_strb = Vec(c.dataBits/8, pingen())
  val w_last = pingen()
  val w_ready  = pingen()
  val w_valid  = pingen()


  val b_bits  = new AXI4BundleB_pin(()=>pingen(),c) 
  val b_ready  = pingen()
  val b_valid  = pingen()

  val ar_id     = Vec(c.idBits, pingen())
  val ar_addr   = Vec(c.addrBits, pingen())
  val ar_len    = Vec(c.lenBits, pingen())  // number of beats - 1
  val ar_size   = Vec(c.sizeBits, pingen()) // bytes in beat = 2^size
  val ar_burst  = Vec(c.burstBits, pingen())
  val ar_lock   = Vec(c.lockBits, pingen())
  val ar_cache  = Vec(c.cacheBits, pingen())
  val ar_prot   = Vec(c.protBits, pingen())
  val ar_qos    = Vec(c.qosBits, pingen())  // 0=no QoS, bigger = higher priority
  val ar_valid =  pingen()
  val ar_ready =  pingen()

  val r_bits  = new AXI4BundleR_pin(()=>pingen(),c)
  val r_ready  = pingen()
  val r_valid  = pingen()
}

object AXI4PinsFromPort {

  def apply[T <: Pin](pins: AXI4_Pins[T], port: AXI4Bundle, clock: Clock, reset: Bool, syncStages: Int = 0, driveStrength: Bool = false.B){

    // This will just match up the components of the Bundle that
    // exist in both.
    withClockAndReset(clock, reset) {
 pins.aw_id.zipWithIndex.map { case (p, i) =>
      p.outputPin(port.aw.bits.id(i), pue=true.B, ie = true.B)
    }
    pins.aw_addr.zipWithIndex.map { case (p, i) =>
      p.outputPin(port.aw.bits.addr(i), pue=true.B, ie = true.B)
    }
    pins.aw_len.zipWithIndex.map { case (p, i) =>
      p.outputPin(port.aw.bits.len(i), pue=true.B, ie = true.B)
    }
    pins.aw_size.zipWithIndex.map { case (p, i) =>
       p.outputPin(port.aw.bits.size(i), pue=true.B, ie = true.B)
    }
    pins.aw_burst.zipWithIndex.map { case (p, i) =>
      p.outputPin(port.aw.bits.burst(i), pue=true.B, ie = true.B)
    }
    pins.aw_lock.zipWithIndex.map { case (p, i) =>
      p.outputPin(port.aw.bits.lock(i), pue=true.B, ie = true.B)
    }
    pins.aw_cache.zipWithIndex.map { case (p, i) =>
      p.outputPin(port.aw.bits.cache(i), pue=true.B, ie = true.B)
    }
    pins.aw_prot.zipWithIndex.map { case (p, i) =>
      p.outputPin(port.aw.bits.prot(i), pue=true.B, ie = true.B)
    }
    pins.aw_qos.zipWithIndex.map { case (p, i) =>
      p.outputPin(port.aw.bits.qos(i), pue=true.B, ie = true.B)
    }
    pins.aw_valid.outputPin(port.aw.valid, pue=true.B, ie = true.B)
    port.aw.ready := pins.aw_ready.inputPin(pue = true.B)




    pins.w_data.zipWithIndex.map { case (p, i) =>
      p.outputPin(port.w.bits.data(i), pue=true.B, ie = true.B)
    }
    pins.w_strb.zipWithIndex.map { case (p, i) =>
      p.outputPin(port.w.bits.strb(i), pue=true.B, ie = true.B)
    }
      pins.w_last.outputPin(port.w.bits.last, pue=true.B, ie = true.B)
    pins.w_valid.outputPin(port.w.valid, pue=true.B, ie = true.B)
    port.w.ready := pins.w_ready.inputPin(pue = true.B)



    val b_bits_pin = Wire(pins.b_bits)
    port.b :=  b_bits_pin
    port.b.valid := pins.b_valid.inputPin(pue = true.B)
    pins.b_ready.outputPin(port.b.ready, pue=true.B, ie = true.B)


    pins.ar_id.zipWithIndex.map { case (p, i) =>
      p.outputPin(port.ar.bits.id(i), pue=true.B, ie = true.B)
    }
    pins.ar_addr.zipWithIndex.map { case (p, i) =>
      p.outputPin(port.ar.bits.addr(i), pue=true.B, ie = true.B)
    }
    pins.ar_len.zipWithIndex.map { case (p, i) =>
      p.outputPin(port.ar.bits.len(i), pue=true.B, ie = true.B)
    }
    pins.ar_size.zipWithIndex.map { case (p, i) =>
      p.outputPin(port.ar.bits.size(i), pue=true.B, ie = true.B)
    }
    pins.ar_burst.zipWithIndex.map { case (p, i) =>
      p.outputPin(port.ar.bits.burst(i), pue=true.B, ie = true.B)
    }
    pins.ar_lock.zipWithIndex.map { case (p, i) =>
      p.outputPin(port.ar.bits.lock(i), pue=true.B, ie = true.B)
    }
    pins.ar_cache.zipWithIndex.map { case (p, i) =>
      p.outputPin(port.ar.bits.cache(i), pue=true.B, ie = true.B)
    }
    pins.ar_prot.zipWithIndex.map { case (p, i) =>
      p.outputPin(port.ar.bits.prot(i), pue=true.B, ie = true.B)
    }
    pins.ar_qos.zipWithIndex.map { case (p, i) =>
      p.outputPin(port.ar.bits.qos(i), pue=true.B, ie = true.B)
    }
    pins.ar_valid.outputPin(port.ar.valid, pue=true.B, ie = true.B)
    port.ar.ready  := pins.ar_ready.inputPin(pue = true.B)

    val r_bits_pin = Wire(pins.r_bits)
    port.r := r_bits_pin
    port.r.valid := pins.r_valid.inputPin(pue = true.B)
    pins.r_ready.outputPin(port.r.ready, pue=true.B, ie = true.B)

    }
  }
}
```

And then at the top of system, the codes are like this:

```
class E300Nexys4DDRDevKitPlatformIO(implicit val p: Parameters) extends Bundle {
  val pins = new Bundle {
    val jtag = new JTAGPins(() => PinGen(), false)
    val gpio = new GPIOPins(() => PinGen(), p(PeripheryGPIOKey)(0))
    val qspi = new SPIPins(() => PinGen(), p(PeripherySPIFlashKey)(0))
    val seg7 = new Seg7LEDPins(() => PinGen())
    val vga  = new VGAPins(() => PinGen())
    val aon  = new MockAONWrapperPins()
    val axi  = new AXI4_Pins(() => PinGen(), p(PeripheryaxiKey)(0))  //added by me
   }
  val jtag_reset = Bool(INPUT)
  val ndreset    = Bool(OUTPUT)
}

....
 // Dedicated AXI Pads
  AXI4PinsFromPort(io.pins.axi, sys.mmio_axi4(0), clock = sys.clock, reset = sys.reset)
```

Where I was wrong? I ve stuck at this stuff for a month. **I m deeply frustrated**. Does anyone help me out?

//2020 June 10th updated

Thank to  Jack Koenig 's reply.

i ve tired add dontTouch to both E300Nexys4DDRDevKitPlatformIO initialization and in the cake pattern. Like this.

[image: cake pattern]

[image: E300Nexys4DDRDevKitPlatformIO initialization]

But sadly it still don't work.

but had inspire me to look at the top of this system. I found that the gpio 12 and 13 didn't show up either. And these two pins are not been allocated in the top file! See.

```
class E300Nexys4DDRDevKitFPGAChip(implicit override val p: Parameters) extends Nexys4DDRShell {

  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Clock divider
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
  val slow_clock = Wire(Bool())

  // Divide clock by 256, used to generate 32.768 kHz clock for AON block
  withClockAndReset(clock_8MHz, ~mmcm_locked) {
    val clockToggleReg = RegInit(false.B)
    val (_, slowTick) = Counter(true.B, 256)
    when (slowTick) {clockToggleReg := ~clockToggleReg}
    slow_clock := clockToggleReg
  }

  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
  // DUT
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------

  withClockAndReset(clock_32MHz, ~ck_rst) {
    val dut = Module(new E300Nexys4DDRDevKitPlatform)

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------
    // SPI flash IOBUFs
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------

    STARTUPE2(dut.io.pins.qspi.sck.o.oval)
    IOBUF(qspi_cs,  dut.io.pins.qspi.cs(0))

    IOBUF(qspi_dq(0), dut.io.pins.qspi.dq(0))
    IOBUF(qspi_dq(1), dut.io.pins.qspi.dq(1))
    IOBUF(qspi_dq(2), dut.io.pins.qspi.dq(2))
    IOBUF(qspi_dq(3), dut.io.pins.qspi.dq(3))

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------
    // JTAG IOBUFs
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------

    dut.io.pins.jtag.TCK.i.ival := IBUFG(IOBUF(jd_2).asClock).asUInt

    IOBUF(jd_5, dut.io.pins.jtag.TMS)
    PULLUP(jd_5)

    IOBUF(jd_4, dut.io.pins.jtag.TDI)
    PULLUP(jd_4)

    IOBUF(jd_0, dut.io.pins.jtag.TDO)

    // mimic putting a pullup on this line (part of reset vote)
    SRST_n := IOBUF(jd_6)
    PULLUP(jd_6)

    // jtag reset
    val jtag_power_on_reset = PowerOnResetFPGAOnly(clock_32MHz)
    dut.io.jtag_reset := jtag_power_on_reset

    // debug reset
    dut_ndreset := dut.io.ndreset

    // UART
    IOBUF(uart_txd_in, dut.io.pins.gpio.pins(16))
    IOBUF(uart_rxd_out, dut.io.pins.gpio.pins(17))
    val iobuf_uart_cts = Module(new IOBUF())
    iobuf_uart_cts.io.I := false.B
    iobuf_uart_cts.io.T := false.B

    // Mirror outputs of GPIOs with PWM peripherals to RGB LEDs on Arty
    // assign RGB LED0 R,G,B inputs = PWM0(1,2,3) when iof_1 is active
    IOBUF(led0_r, dut.io.pins.gpio.pins(1))
    IOBUF(led0_g, dut.io.pins.gpio.pins(2))
    IOBUF(led0_b, dut.io.pins.gpio.pins(3))

    // Note that this is the one which is actually connected on the HiFive/Crazy88
    // Board. Same with RGB LED1 R,G,B inputs = PWM1(1,2,3) when iof_1 is active
    IOBUF(led1_r, dut.io.pins.gpio.pins(19))
    IOBUF(led1_g, dut.io.pins.gpio.pins(21))
    IOBUF(led1_b, dut.io.pins.gpio.pins(22))

    // Only 19 out of 20 shield pins connected to GPIO pins
    // Shield pin A5 (pin 14) left unconnected
    // The buttons are connected to some extra GPIO pins not connected on the
    // HiFive1 board
    IOBUF(btn_0, dut.io.pins.gpio.pins(15))
    IOBUF(btn_1, dut.io.pins.gpio.pins(30))
    IOBUF(btn_2, dut.io.pins.gpio.pins(31))

    val iobuf_btn_3 = Module(new IOBUF())
    iobuf_btn_3.io.I := ~dut.io.pins.aon.pmu.dwakeup_n.o.oval
    iobuf_btn_3.io.T := ~dut.io.pins.aon.pmu.dwakeup_n.o.oe
    attach(btn_3, iobuf_btn_3.io.IO)
    dut.io.pins.aon.pmu.dwakeup_n.i.ival := ~iobuf_btn_3.io.O & dut.io.pins.aon.pmu.dwakeup_n.o.ie

    // UART1 RX/TX pins are assigned to PMOD_D connector pins 0/1
    IOBUF(ja_0, dut.io.pins.gpio.pins(25)) // UART1 TX
    IOBUF(ja_1, dut.io.pins.gpio.pins(24)) // UART1 RX

    // Use the LEDs for some more useful debugging things
    IOBUF(led_0, ck_rst)
    IOBUF(led_1, SRST_n)
    IOBUF(led_2, dut.io.pins.aon.pmu.dwakeup_n.i.ival)
    IOBUF(led_3, dut.io.pins.gpio.pins(14))

    IOBUF(led_4, dut.io.pins.gpio.pins(4))
    IOBUF(led_5, dut.io.pins.gpio.pins(5))
    IOBUF(led_6, dut.io.pins.gpio.pins(6))
    IOBUF(led_7, dut.io.pins.gpio.pins(7))
    IOBUF(led_8, dut.io.pins.gpio.pins(8))
    IOBUF(led_9, dut.io.pins.gpio.pins(9))
    IOBUF(led_10, dut.io.pins.gpio.pins(10))
    IOBUF(led_11, dut.io.pins.gpio.pins(11))
    IOBUF(led_12, dut.io.pins.gpio.pins(26))
    IOBUF(led_13, dut.io.pins.gpio.pins(27))
    IOBUF(led_14, dut.io.pins.gpio.pins(28))
    IOBUF(led_15, dut.io.pins.gpio.pins(29))

    // Seg 7 LED
    IOBUF(seg7_ca, dut.io.pins.seg7.cathodes(0))
    IOBUF(seg7_cb, dut.io.pins.seg7.cathodes(1))
    IOBUF(seg7_cc, dut.io.pins.seg7.cathodes(2))
    IOBUF(seg7_cd, dut.io.pins.seg7.cathodes(3))
    IOBUF(seg7_ce, dut.io.pins.seg7.cathodes(4))
    IOBUF(seg7_cf, dut.io.pins.seg7.cathodes(5))
    IOBUF(seg7_cg, dut.io.pins.seg7.cathodes(6))

    IOBUF(seg7_dp, dut.io.pins.seg7.decimalPoint)

    IOBUF(seg7_an_0, dut.io.pins.seg7.anodes(0))
    IOBUF(seg7_an_1, dut.io.pins.seg7.anodes(1))
    IOBUF(seg7_an_2, dut.io.pins.seg7.anodes(2))
    IOBUF(seg7_an_3, dut.io.pins.seg7.anodes(3))
    IOBUF(seg7_an_4, dut.io.pins.seg7.anodes(4))
    IOBUF(seg7_an_5, dut.io.pins.seg7.anodes(5))
    IOBUF(seg7_an_6, dut.io.pins.seg7.anodes(6))
    IOBUF(seg7_an_7, dut.io.pins.seg7.anodes(7))

    // VGA Display
    IOBUF(vga_red_0, dut.io.pins.vga.red(0))
    IOBUF(vga_red_1, dut.io.pins.vga.red(1))
    IOBUF(vga_red_2, dut.io.pins.vga.red(2))
    IOBUF(vga_red_3, dut.io.pins.vga.red(3))

    IOBUF(vga_green_0, dut.io.pins.vga.green(0))
    IOBUF(vga_green_1, dut.io.pins.vga.green(1))
    IOBUF(vga_green_2, dut.io.pins.vga.green(2))
    IOBUF(vga_green_3, dut.io.pins.vga.green(3))

    IOBUF(vga_blue_0, dut.io.pins.vga.blue(0))
    IOBUF(vga_blue_1, dut.io.pins.vga.blue(1))
    IOBUF(vga_blue_2, dut.io.pins.vga.blue(2))
    IOBUF(vga_blue_3, dut.io.pins.vga.blue(3))

    IOBUF(vga_hSync, dut.io.pins.vga.hSync)
    IOBUF(vga_vSync, dut.io.pins.vga.vSync)

    dut.io.pins.vga.clock := clock_25MHz
    dut.io.pins.vga.reset := ~ck_rst

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Unconnected inputs
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------

    dut.io.pins.aon.erst_n.i.ival       := ~reset_periph
    dut.io.pins.aon.lfextclk.i.ival     := slow_clock
    dut.io.pins.aon.pmu.vddpaden.i.ival := 1.U
  }
}
```

So I was wondering if I can tune it a little bit to solve this problem. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Is the module you shared the IO of the top-level module in the design? If not then the ports may be getting optimized away if they are unused in the parent module. You can try calling `chisel3.dontTouch` on the instantiation of `E300Nexys4DDRDevKitPlatformIO` to prevent optimizations on that interface.

Comment: Thank you, I just tried, but still don't work, I checked the top code, found that the gpio12 and gpio13 are still been optimized because it didn't been allocate to any Xilinx pins on the top. So I wonder if I can change the top file a liitle bit to enable the axi4 port.

Comment: What is the value of `p(PeripheryaxiKey)`? Try `println`ing it, I'm guess it's set to `false` or some way of saying there should be no AXI